# Can't call one parse method from another parse method in scrapy spider

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy. while learning Scrapy, i faced one problem that i couldn't call one parse method from another parse method in scrapy spider.

Here's my spider.py file code:

**some_spider.py**

```
import scrapy
class SomeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider_1'
    start_urls = ['https://www.xxxxxx.xxx/xxxx-xxxx/xxxxxx']

    def parse(self, response):
        for element in response.xpath('//div/ul/li')[1:]: # skipped first list element used '[1:]'
            element_href = element.xpath('a/@href').extract_first()
            element_text = element.xpath('a/text()').extract_first().strip()
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(element_href), callback=self.parse_element_1, meta = {'element': element_text})

    def parse_element_1(self, response):
        for element1 in response.xpath('//div/ul/li'):
            element1_href = element1.xpath('a/@href').extract_first()
            element1_text = element1.xpath('a/text()').extract_first().strip()
            element = response.meta['element']
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(element1_href), callback=self.parse_element_2, meta={'element': element, 'element1': element1_text})

    def parse_element_2(self, response):
        for element2 in response.xpath('//div'):
            element2_href = element2.xpath('a/@href').extract_first()
            element = response.meta['element']
            element1 = response.meta['element1']
            yield {
               'element': element,
               'element1': element1
               }
```

In above code, i couldn't call **parse_element_2()** from **parse_element_1()** method. i could call **parse_element_2()** from **parse()** method. and it's not giving me any error and keep crawling web-site.

and i am running spider using following command :

```
scrapy crawl spider_1 -o scraped_data.json
```

So, Please Help me to sort out this problem. and i have one more question,

Can we create multiple parse methods within single spider class?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post the crawl log? `scrapy crawl spider 2>&1 > crawl.log` for example. My guess would be you have some duplicate urls here and srapy filters them out, you can try adding `dont_filter` parameter to your Request i.e. `Request(dont_filter=True)` and see it fixes it, however then that means something is wrong with your crawl logic that it recrawls the same page multiple times without explicit reason.

Comment: @Granitosaurus i have used that `Request(dont_filter=True)`. but still problem is there. i think there could be something wrong with the crawl logic. i have created crawl.log file but it's blank.

Comment: @Nikunj, what do you mean by _"i couldn't call one parse method from another parse method"_? What happens? an error? missing expected data?